# Two miscellaneous questions about equations involving the Euler's totient function and twin primes

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, oeis

This morning I was thinking in equations involving the Euler's totient function $\varphi(n)$ and the sequence of twin primes (see if you want this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TwinPrimes.html)). I am saying similar questions than statements or conjectures that were in the literature. Since my questions are miscellaneous and I have done few experiments, I preferred to group these questions in the same post.

I was inspired in the sequence `A037171` from [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/) to ask about the first question.

I don't know if next sequence was in the literature, and how to prove that has finitely many terms. My sequence is defined as the integers $n\geq 1$ that satisfy $$\pi_2(n^2)=\varphi(n),\tag{1}$$
where $\pi_2(x)$ is the twin prime counting function. Our sequence starts as $3,5,7,11,13$, and since I know only these terms I cann't know if our sequence is in the OEIS. Also I tried to combine formulas from the literature to prove that our sequence is finite, but the factor $k^2$ 
the factor spoiled my proof from the strategy $\pi_2(x)<\pi(x)$. Thus my main question here is the next.

> **Question 1.** Do you know this sequence $(1)$ from the OEIS or a different official source? **Many thanks for yor attention.**

Also this morning I was exploring the sequence `A001359` from the OEIS, then I known the [first comment by McCranie (2001) and the subsequent comment](http://oeis.org/A001359). My first idea was to generalize with next conejcture.

**Conjecture .** A) If $n\geq 1$ satisfies $$\varphi((n+2)^2)=(n+2)\cdot(\sigma(n^2)-n^2)\tag{2}$$
then $n$ and $n+2$ are a pair of twin primes (that is $n$ and $n+2$ are primes).

B) With $\sigma(l)=\sum_{d\mid l}d$ we denote here the sum of divisors function. If an integer $n\geq 1$ satisfies, for a fixed integer $a\geq 2$, the equation  $$n\varphi((n+2)^a)=(n-1)\sigma(n^a)+n^2\left(\sum_{k=1}^{a-1}\binom{a-1}{k}n^{a-1-k}\cdot 2^k\right)+(n+1)^2,\tag{3}$$ 
then $n$ and $n+2$ are primes, that is, $(n,n+2)$ is a pair of twin primes.$\square$

I don't know if there exists a more elegant generalization of McCranie's conjecture. To me it is difficult even to prove the implication that 
I omitted, and I've no intuition if there are integers $m$ satisfying $(3)$ but also $m\notin\text{A001359}$ for some fixed integer $a\geq 2$.

> **Question 2.** Can you tabulate counterexamples $(m,a)$ of Conjecture B  for the first (for each fixed) integers $a\geq 2$? That I am asking is if you can find counterexamples for the first integers $a\geq 2$, say us integers $m\geq 3$ satisfying
>   $$m\varphi((m+2)^a)=(m-1)\sigma(m^a)+m^2\left(\sum_{k=1}^{a-1}\binom{a-1}{k}m^{a-1-k}\cdot 2^k\right)+(m+1)^2$$
>   **and also** $m\notin\text{A001359}$. **Many thanks.**

Comment: About Question 2, sincerely I would like to know a more elegant  generalization than $(3)$ of a pretentious (mine) characterization for twin primes, but the main question in the Question 2, is if we  can find an easy counterexample (my attention is only for the first $a≥2$ and the first hundreds of $m$).

Comment: Are you looking for a proof of (A)? How have you tried to prove it?

Comment: I am not looking a proof of $(A)$, that is the conjecture concerning the identity $(2)$, since I think that it should be very difficult or impossible. Notice that I've added two questions and I did not want to add any more  questions. I think that this identity is more elegant than the identity $(3)$ and could be nice to know if is it possible to get a characterization of twin primes using $(2)$. Many thanks @MatthewConroy

Comment: Well, I have a proof for (A) if you would like it.

Comment: Perfect @MatthewConroy , I think that it is right if you want to share it, then I am wait if some user want to do feedback about if my $(3)$ is nice in comparison with your $(2)$: in fact I've created $(3)$ for twin primes, but I didn't write a rigurous proof of the easy implication (and $(3)$ is a conjecture, that is the difficult implication in my pretentious characterization).

Comment: since $\varphi(n^2)=n\varphi(n)$ you could divide both sides of (2) by $n+2$ giving
$\varphi(n+2)=\sigma(n^2)-n^2$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof that $$\varphi((n+2)^2)=(n+2)\cdot(\sigma(n^2)-n^2)$$ if and only if $n$ and $n+2$ are both primes.

Suppose $n+2$ is prime.

Then $$\varphi((n+2)^2) = (n+2)^2\left(1-\frac{1}{n+2} \right)=n^2+3n+2.$$

For *any* $n$, $$(n+2)^2(\sigma(n^2)-n^2) \ge (n+2)^2(n+1) = n^2+3n+2$$ with 
equality only if $n$ is prime.  Thus, the equality is established when $n$ and $n+2$ are prime.

Now, suppose $n+2$ is not prime.  Then 
$$\varphi((n+2)^2) = (n+2)^2 \prod_{p|n+2} \left( 1-\frac{1}{p} \right)
\le (n+2)^2 \left( 1 - \frac{2}{n+2}\right) = n^2+2n.$$

Since $n^2+2n<n^2+3n+2$ for all $n>0$, the equality fails to hold if $n$ and $n+2$ are not both prime.

Comment: (1/2) Many thanks for this great proof. I would like to add that, of course, the credit of this new characterization of twin primes is your. Next is a present if you want to explore it: For $n>1$ and $\gcd(p,n)=1$, $p$ a prime number and $a\geq 1$ an integer one has $$\sigma(n)+\delta(p^an)\equiv -1\text{ mod }p,\tag{1}$$
where $\delta(m)=\rho(m)-\rho(m-1)$ with $\rho(m)$ the sum of remainders function (see this [JSTOR: *The Humble Sum of Remainders Function*, Mathematics Magazine
Vol. 78, No. 4 by Michael Z. Spivey](https://www.jstor.org/stable/30044176?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents),

Comment: (2/2) I can read it from MyJSTOR account). Thus if $n$ and $n+2$ are twin primes and $p$ a different prime one has $$2+\delta(p^a(n+2))\equiv \delta(p^a n)\text{ mod }p.\tag{2}$$
I didn't experiments, and maybe (I'm not sure) is an idea to try to combine (also you can read online it from JSTOR) with Maria Suzuki, *Alternative Formulations of the Twin
Prime Problem*, The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 107, No. 1, January 2000. I say on assumption that the twin prime conjecture fails). Thus these remarks are if you want to do experiments and calculations about previous invlving $\rho(m)$.